# AssertEqual between string and Selenium Text - why does it fail?

Tags: c#, string, selenium, whitespace, assert

I have test data in an XML format, and the Text or Value from a WebElement (Selenium).

I compare both values and the Assert fails. Initially the XML whitespaces (due to formatting) were the obvious issue, but having removed them, I still get the following result.
I have pasted the error log in Word and have no visual difference in spacing characters anymore.

[image: Output of Assert]

**Edit:**
Further investigation shows that the Assert fails on the newline character.
When copying to Word, the whitespace following this character is different between the expected and actual result.

**Edit 2:**
The hexcode in decimal is 13 versus 10 so they are different characters.
The question is how to convert one to the other?

Comment: Have you tried comparing them character by character to determine at which character it 'fails'?

Comment: Good tip, edited my question with the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings that are being compared have a mixture of Line Feeds (Decimal = 10, `\n`) and Carriage Returns (Decimal = 13, `\r`).

---

I think the easiest solution would be to normalize the strings:

```
yourString.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace('\r', '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should specify correct  [CultureInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140926/normalize-newlines-in-c-sharp). For example:

```
Assert.AreEqual(s1, s2, false, new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Additionally, you can try normalize your strings line endings:
  [Normalize newlines in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140926/normalize-newlines-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Tried to add CultureInfo.InvariantCulture but that didn't work.

Comment: Yes, after your comment about line endings, I think changing culture won't work. You can try comparing text by lines as workaround (split them with String.Split()).

Comment: And split by which character?

Comment: Try something like this: s.Split(new string[] {System.Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: Have you tried string normalization, because it looks like one string has "\r\n" line ending and the other one "\n"?